# How to Implement Global Action (Functionality) for All Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, extension-methods

We are developing .NET MVC 5 project and we have document generation toolkit which must be used and available globally on every controller.

The main idea is if there is any document related with a controller or an action, the user need to access that document inside that controller. basicly, I have a table which stores areaname, controller, action and related document id. If the user click "show documents" button in any screen. System checks whether there are documents available for specified area,controller and action, and if there is, the available documents needed to be shown to the user for further action.

so, for this purpose, I read several documents and I ended up with a method. But, I am not sure whether this is correct approach or not.

One way is extending controller with "Extension By Delegion" which is referenced in [this post](http://antix.co.uk/Blog/Extending-the-MVC-Controller)

If you have any suggestions, please give me feedback.

thank you

Comment: Why won't you make some kind of a BaseController class from which all/some of your controllers inherit from?

Comment: I thought it actually, but In that case, I need to use that base controller everywhere. So all of my controllers need to depend on that baseController. I thought that there must be another more common way to do it.

Comment: I don't see a better alternative. And think about it. You can theoretically make such more base controllers and you don't must inherent each controller from a base one. You have degrees of freedom.